# Increasing the weight in metal with salt?

Tags: metal, salt

Is it possible to increase the weight in metal (such as bronze) by exposing it, or soaking it in salt?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. The only possible effect is the oxidation of the metal due to the air. But the increase of mass is so small that it would even be difficult to measure. Soaking in salt has no effect on the weight. Anyway the mass of the metal will never increase, whatever the treatment, with or without salt. The increase in mass corresponds to the oxygen being fixed as oxide on the surface of the metallic piece. The mass of the metal itself cannot and will not change.